# Birthday & Anniversary Webpart (Slider)

Tags: list, library, picture, conditional

I would like to create an share point web part (slider) on wiki page to display today's birthday and anniversaries with picture and description (like Date of birth, name, year in company etc).

Since, I am new in SharePoint and don't know much about SharePoint development, would someone please help me with step by step process to create SharePoint Web part which I can add to the page.

I am not administrator of the SharePoint and only the owner of a site.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This post describes in detail on how to create a Birthday webpart in SharePoint: https://www.sharepointfire.com/2016/06/sharepoint-online-birthday-and-anniversary-web-part-using-search-results/

Summary:

- Create a managed search property (and make sure it's indexed before you continue)
- Add a search result webpart to the page
- Configure the webpart to show the relevant people
- Create a custom display template to make the result look nice

Comment: This feature helpful. However, I don't have access to these features of SharePoint. Would like to know if there any other option using jquery etc.

Comment: I don't know. You need to fetch the birtdate from sowewhere and if you want to use the user profiles for that, you need to change the search schema

Comment: Birthdate will be pulled from sharepoint list.